# jQuery alert/output out elements help

Tags: jquery

I need some help understanding how jQuery stores elements.  Please have a look at this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/NubWC/

I am trying to get the element id from all the heading tags that have a specific class and put that into an array so I can do something with it.  In the link you will see I tried to do that and alert out but it only alerts the first ID returned and not all of them.  How do I go about something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
var heading = [];
$("h1.expanded").each(function() {
    heading.push($(this).attr("id")); 
});
alert(heading);
```

You need to explicitly make the array, and use the `.each` jQuery function to loop through all the elements that match your selector.

Comment: Thanks!- and I am assuming to get the data back out, I could also use each() function?

Comment: Kind of. You need to use different syntax: $.each(heading, function() { //do something }); going back through the array. Check out the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) here

```
var idArr = $("h1.expanded").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();

alert (idArr.join(','));
```

See your demo [**edited**](http://jsfiddle.net/NubWC/2/)

Answer (score 0):

map is faster then each.

```
var heading= $("h1.expanded").map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get().join(' ');
alert(heading);
```

Check performance log at http://jsperf.com/array-test000